# How to make post request with form in React

Tags: reactjs

After i filled the inputs and submitted the form, I want to make a POST request with React. When i use `fetch` outside the `handleSubmit` function with a static name and job value, it works. But if i use inside the `handleSubmit` function, it doesn't work. Why? and how can i solve this?

```
import React from "react";

function CreateUser() {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: `${e.target.name.value}`,
        job: `${e.target.job.value}`,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />

      <label htmlFor="job">job</label>
      <input id="job" name="job" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default CreateUser;
```

Comment: When you inspect the network tab in your dev tools, is the call being made? If so, can you check the request data to make sure it's sending the value from your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check how to use `fetch` correctly. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api you need to return response.

Your react code seems fine, not sure how are you trying to handle success and error.

Check following Sandbox which I created using your code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-breeze-7fx2g?file=/src/App.js